# Creating and saving a table (.png) with Pandas in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, png

I would like to create and save a table in Python, using the Pandas package.

This is my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd

column1 = ['Measured Set', '1. set', '2. set', '3. set']
column2= ['Breached parameter(s) (Number of breaches / %)', 3, 3, 3]
column3 = ['Breached parameter(s) (Number of breaches / %)', 3, 3, 3]

data = {
    'Sensor': column1,
    'Sensor 1': column2,
    'Sensor 2': column3,
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

This is my output:[image]

And this is what I would like to get:
[image]

So I would like to:

1. Replace the automatically generated left column with the one next to it,
2. Shade the 2nd row and left column
3. Save the table as a .png file

Could someone help me with this issue?

Comment: If you only have to do this a small number of times, I'd suggest simply copy-pasting the `pandas` output to MS Excel, formatting as desired, and taking a screenshot.

Comment: Add the code How are you get your Output _**This is my output:enter image description here_**?

Comment: its a printscreen